# Django: Can't save empty form field to database - invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, database, django, forms, sqlite

Many people report this type of error, but so far none of the fixes worked for me. I have a model that has an IntegerField allowing for null values:

```
def SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    price_sell = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ...
```

Then I have a form that goes like this:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    price_sell = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    ...
```

When leaving this field empty, and calling the save method, I get a `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` error. I tried many things having to do with the blank and null parameters, but no luck so far.

My solution has been to do this is my views.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
    if(request.POST['price_sell'] == ''):
        price_sell = None
    ...
```

But I am certain there is a more elegant way to do this. Or is there not?

I'm running Django 1.6 on Windows with SQLite db.

Comment: @Charles I made the edit to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the data from the cleaned_data in the form.  The `IntegerField` will get you what you want.  `form.cleaned_data['price_sell']`